# How do I delete all of the music on my iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, icloud, music

I have tried to delete all of the music off through iTunes and through settings. the computer and settings says it is gone but when i go to the music app it is all still there just not downloaded. all of my songs are shown but they have the cloud icon with the arrow pointing down next to them. I went them all gone to the point that I can't even see them on my phone. How do i do this?